Как избавиться от ошибки - Error: registerCurrentComponent: no current owner?
Как избавиться от ошибки - Error: registerCurrentComponent: no current owner?
На локальном хосте она не выпадает, после успешной сборки и запуске на github pages появляется эта ошибка. При локализации ошибки выяснилось что она выпадет при использовании StringToReactComponent. Также пытался пропустить ошибку с помощью ErrorBoundary и window.onerror пока ничего не вышло.
